# How can I insert values into a table with a composite primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, sql-insert, primary-key

These are the tables I already have:

```
CREATE TABLE Gyartok 
(
    GyID INT IDENTITY(2, 3),
    Nev VARCHAR(20),

    CONSTRAINT PK_Gyartok PRIMARY KEY (GyID)
)

CREATE TABLE Focicsuka 
(
    CsID INT IDENTITY(2, 2),
    Meret INT, 

    CONSTRAINT PK_Focicsuka PRIMARY KEY (CsID)
)

CREATE TABLE FcsGyartjaGya 
(
    GyID INT IDENTITY(3, 2), 
    CsID INT,
    Ar INT,

    CONSTRAINT FK_FcsGyartjaGya1 
        FOREIGN KEY (GyID) REFERENCES Gyartok(GyID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_FcsGyartjaGya2 
        FOREIGN KEY (CsID) REFERENCES Focicsuka(CsID),
    CONSTRAINT PK_FcsGyartjaGya 
        PRIMARY KEY (GyID, CsID)
)
```

The problem is that every time I try to add new values to the table (like such)

```
INSERT INTO FcsGyartjaGya (Ar) VALUES (300);
```

I get an error saying I didn't initialize the CsID INT column:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CsID', table 'Lab3.dbo.FcsGyartjaGya'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

I know I must initialize it with something, but I have no idea what do to it with, because `IDENTITY(x, y)` doesn't work (it's occupied by another column already) and adding another parameter to the code (like such)

```
INSERT INTO FcsGyartjaGya (Ar, CsID) VALUES (300, 7);
```

creates another error which says

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_FcsGyartjaGya1". The conflict occurred in database "Lab3a", table "dbo.Gyartok", column 'GyID'.

It is important to note that I already filled every column with data, so that couldn't be the problem.

Comment: The column `CsID` (in the table `FcsGyartjaGya`) *can't* be `NULL`; so you **must** provide a value; what that value is we don't know. If `CsID` should be `NULL`able, then it shouldn't be part of the Primary Key.

Comment: @Larnu How can I assign a value to it though? It doesn't let me do it in any way I know

Comment: @T.S.
`INSERT INTO FcsGyartjaGya (Ar) VALUES (300, 20);`
throws this
`There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.`

Comment: Your second statement would work, *if* the value (`7)` existed in the table `Focicsuka`. But, also, having a column that is an `IDENTITY` be a `FOREIGN KEY` is just a bad idea. You're effectively leaving things to chance. I smell a strong [XY problem](//xyproblem.info) here.

Comment: Because you are not understanding your schema. Table FcsGyartjaGya is an intersection table between the other two tables, It forms a relationship between a row that exist in Gyartok and a row that exists in Focicsuka. YOU (or your code) must supply the appropriate PK values from these two tables during insertion. The database will not assign values from a random row nor will it let you "work" on this table by first inserting your row and then updating it with values from the other two tables.

Comment: @SMor  _YOU must supply the appropriate PK values from these two tables during insertion_
 and how do I do that?

Comment: You need to use `INSERT INTO FcsGyartjaGya (Ar, CsId) VALUES (300, 20);` - **always** specify all the columns you want to insert values into. And the number of columns specified must match the number of values provided

Comment: If the stars align correctly, your `INSERT` works fine: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a4e35e923c24c0f535141b14465ef1c7) So, for your design, that would be when `{IDENTITY Value} + 1` is divisible by both 2 and 3 and the value exists. I.e. 5, 11, 17, 23...

Comment: @dancus25 You must have previously inserted the appropriate rows in the other two tables at some point in the past - perhaps immediately before you attempt your current insert if you are in the process of creating a new "set" of whatever your tables represent. Seems you should probably have a discussion with your group and the database designer to understand the schema and how to work with it. Or simply start your discussion from a higher level or at the start of your process. No one can tell you what IDs from the other tables you should be using.

Comment: @Larnu I can't seem to understand the comments above the insert into parts from the link you sent.
`--Works, there is a GyID with the value 5
INSERT INTO dbo.FcsGyartjaGya (CsID,Ar)
VALUES(2,2);
`
how does this work here, and why does GyID influence this command?

Comment: With respect, what about *"Fails, no GyID with the value 3"* is confusing you..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mention in the comments, your `INSERT` will work fine, provided the stars align correctly. For your table `Gyartok` you have `GyID` as your `PRIMARY KEY`, which is defined as a `IDENTITY(2,3)`; so the first value generated is `2` and then each row *attempted* to be `INSERT`ed will increment by `3`.

So, if we run the following, we get the IDs 2, 5, 7 and 17. (11 and 14 are skipped as the `INSERT` failed).

```sql
CREATE TABLE Gyartok (
    GyID INT IDENTITY(2, 3),
    Nev VARCHAR(20),
    CONSTRAINT PK_Gyartok PRIMARY KEY (GyID)
);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Gyartok (Nev)
VALUES ('asdfjahsbvd'),
       ('ashjkgdfakd'),
       ('kldfbhjo');
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Gyartok (Nev)
VALUES (REPLICATE('A',25)), --Force a truncation error
       ('ashjkgdfakd');
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Gyartok (Nev)
VALUES (REPLICATE('A',15));
```

Let's now add some data for your other table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Focicsuka (
    CsID INT IDENTITY(2, 2),
    Meret INT, 
    CONSTRAINT PK_Focicsuka PRIMARY KEY (CsID)
)
INSERT INTO dbo.Focicsuka (Meret)
VALUES(12),
      (25);
```

Now we want to `INSERT` into the table `FcsGyartjaGya`, defined as the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE FcsGyartjaGya (
    GyID INT IDENTITY(3, 2), 
    CsID INT,
    Ar INT,

    CONSTRAINT FK_FcsGyartjaGya1 FOREIGN KEY (GyID) REFERENCES Gyartok(GyID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_FcsGyartjaGya2 FOREIGN KEY (CsID) REFERENCES Focicsuka(CsID),
    CONSTRAINT PK_FcsGyartjaGya PRIMARY KEY (GyID, CsID)
)
```

This has a `IDENTITY` on `GyID`, but defined as an `IDENTITY(3,2)`, so the first value is `3` and then incremented by `2`.

As this has 2 foreign keys, on `GyID` and `CsID` when we `INSERT` the row the values must appear in the respective tables. As `GyID` is defined as an`IDENTITY(3,2)` however, this is where we need to rely on <strike>the Stars</strike> luck for the `INSERT` to work. Why? Well `2 + (3*n)` and `3+(2*n)` can give very different numbers. The first are as you saw at the start of this answer. For the latter, we have numbers like `3`, `5`, `7`, `9`, `11`. As you can see, only 1 in 3 of these numbers match a number in our original sequence, so luck is what we are going to be relying on.

Let's, therefore, try a single `INSERT`.

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.FcsGyartjaGya (CsID,Ar)
VALUES(2,1);
```

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_FcsGyartjaGya1". The conflict occurred in database "Sandbox", table "dbo.Gyartok", column 'GyID'.

Well, that didn't work, but it was expected. `3` isn't a value in the table `Gyartok`. Let's try again!

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.FcsGyartjaGya (CsID,Ar)
VALUES(2,2);
```

It worked! <strike>The stars</strike> Luck was our side, and the `IDENTITY` value was a value in the table `Gyartok`. Let's try a couple of rows this time!

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.FcsGyartjaGya (CsID,Ar)
VALUES(4,3),
      (4,4);
```

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_FcsGyartjaGya1". The conflict occurred in database "Sandbox", table "dbo.Gyartok", column 'GyID'.

No!! Not again. :( That's because the stars didn't align; `7` and `9` aren't in the other table. But wait, `11` was in the sequence, so let's try that:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.FcsGyartjaGya (CsID,Ar)
VALUES(4,5);
```

Error, again?! No, it cannot be!!! :( Oh wait, I forgot, the stars were against us before, because that `INSERT` failed against `Gyartok` for the value of `11`. I need to wait for `17`!

```
--13 fails
INSERT INTO dbo.FcsGyartjaGya (CsID,Ar)
VALUES(4,6);
GO
--15 fails
INSERT INTO dbo.FcsGyartjaGya (CsID,Ar)
VALUES(4,6);
GO
--17 works!
INSERT INTO dbo.FcsGyartjaGya (CsID,Ar)
VALUES(4,6);
```

And now we have another row in our table.

---

So what is the problem? Your design. `GyID` is defined as an `IDENTITY` **and** a `FOREIGN KEY`; meaning you are at the "whims" of SQL Server generating a valid value. This is not what you want. Just don't define the column as an `IDENTITY` and then `INSERT` the data with all 3 of your columns defined:

```sql
CREATE TABLE FcsGyartjaGya (
    GyID int,-- IDENTITY(3, 2), 
    CsID INT,
    Ar INT,

    CONSTRAINT FK_FcsGyartjaGya1 FOREIGN KEY (GyID) REFERENCES Gyartok(GyID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_FcsGyartjaGya2 FOREIGN KEY (CsID) REFERENCES Focicsuka(CsID),
    CONSTRAINT PK_FcsGyartjaGya PRIMARY KEY (GyID, CsID)
)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.FcsGyartjaGya (GyID, CsID, Ar)
VALUES(2,2,1),
      (2,4,2),
      (5,4,3),
      (8,2,4),
      (8,4,5);
```

And all these rows insert fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bit confusion, if I understand correctly what You're trying to do, then you have two tables each with their own id, which is based on an identity column, so you get new values in those for free.
Then you are trying to make a relation table with extra data.

Issue 1: You cannot have FcsGyartjaGya.GyID be identity if it refers to Gyartok.GyID because you will want to insert into it and not rely on an auto increment. If it doesn't refer to the same it should have another name or my head will possibly explode :))

Issue 2: When populating a relation table you need to insert it with what pairs you want, there is no way SQL server can know how it should match these identity pairs in the relation table

I think this is what people are aiming at in the comments, for example
to insert a relationship between row with Focicsuka.CsID = 1 to Gyartok.GyID 7 and adding Ar = 300 have to look like

```
INSERT INTO FCSGYARTJAGYA(GYID, CSID, AR)
VALUES(7, 1, 300)
```

Unless You've forgotten to mention that you want to put some value for each of some value or based on something which can be scripted, in other words unless You have logics to define the pairs and their values, relationship tables cannot have defaults on their foreign key fields.